# Laravel: How can I get my friend relationship in a Pivot belongsToMany relation

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a friendship relationship with another user in Laravel and when fetching the relationship, I want to get the user that isnt myself. (either user_id or friend_id)

This is the relationship I have:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'user_id', 'friend_id')
        ->where('user_id', $this->id)
        ->orWhere('friend_id', $this->id);
```

When I am the user_id, I get the friend related

```
   foreach($user->friends as $friend) {
     echo $friend->first_name;
   }
```

But when I am the friend, I get my own name. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need two relations like below.

```php
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}


public function isFriendsWith()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Say a user with id 1 has two entries in the `friend_user` table like

| id | user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

Then you can query relations like

```php
$user1 = User::findOrFail(1);

$user1->friends; //Will get two users with an id of 2 and 5

$user2 = User::findOrFail(2);
$user2->isFriendsWith; //Will get one user with an id of 1
$user2->friends; //Will return empty collection

$user5 = User::findOrFail(5);
$user5->isFriendsWith; //Will get one user with an id of 1
$user5->friends; //Will return empty collection
```